# Logcat shows previous fixed errors?

Tags: android, android-studio

There is something that bothers me in android studio which is the way Logcat keeps showing some errors that have been fixed. Every time I run the emulator they keep appearing again. Although I fixed them as I said. The app doesn't crash but I just don't want them to show up.
Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Clear the logcat on launch!

Comment: In android studio 2.0 and later version the log history is appears even after clearing.

Comment: @UttamPanchasara Yes that is what I noticed. That is kind of annoying!
Maybe it is related to the instant run feature. Hence, we have to clear the logcat and restart the app again.

Comment: Nop there is no any relation with instant run as i know coz after stop the instant run history will b there so.. its better clear history evertime ;) till find the solution

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the Instants run. Android studio is caching some of your code base for faster building and deployment, its much better if you do a build and install every time 
To disable it go to "File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployement -> Instant Run"